# Is there way to use Python Pandas to subtract a specific row from another row?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Portion of my code that's giving trouble below. I open a CSV and want to subtract the 1st row from the last row then append it to a new file. I get an error KeyError: 96 when I try it. I know the problem is the df[96]-df[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acJZl.jpg) but I'm not sure why it's wrong, I've also tried df[96,:]-df[1,:]

df opens a csv that looks like a header description with numbers in each column (30 columns)

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename')

dictionarylist = []

newsum = df[96]-df[1] # I want to subtract row 1 (after header) from row 96 (or whatever the last row is)

dictionarylist.append(newsum)
```

One thing though, I want the output to be in list format so I can add another value in the first value of the list. So the list output would be like listoutput = [-5, 3, 2] and then I can go listoutput[0] = current_date_variable

[image: csv table]
[image: newsum original]

Comment: If 96 and 1 are row indices, you might have more luck with something like `df.iloc[96]-df.iloc[1]`, but can you show an example of what `df` looks like? it will be easier to help

Comment: thank you for your edit! can you also share what you expect `newsum` to be from your example table?

Comment: hi, originally I had newsum look like newsum = (df[row].sum()), but then I realized instead of summing all the rows I wanted to subtract the specified row. So it should be in that same format

Comment: thanks for your explanation, but it would really be helpful if you shared an example table and what you expect `newsum` to be. even a simplified table with just a few columns and rows

Comment: hi, added a picture of what my newsum output looked like before as a row of data and what some of the csv looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `iloc` to select the first and last row and then subtract

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Create a test df
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1':np.random.choice(10,6),
    'col2':np.random.choice(10,6),
    'col3':np.random.choice(10,6),
})

#subtract the first row from the last row
first_ind = 0
last_ind = len(df)-1
diff_row = df.iloc[last_ind]-df.iloc[first_ind]
print(diff_row)
```

Here's the test df that is created:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     5     1     5
1     8     7     2
2     9     6     4
3     5     9     2
4     0     2     4
5     0     4     7
```

And then `diff_row` equals:

```
col1   -5
col2    3
col3    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I think that's it! How would I write the data from that and append it to a new row in a different csv?

Comment: One thing though, I want the output to be in list format so I can add another value in the first value of the list. So the list output would be like listoutput = [-5, 3, 2] and then I can go listoutput[0] = current_date_variable

Comment: you've phrased your new question really well. I think if you search stackoverflow/google you'll find help. as a hint you can take a look at `pandas.append` from the documentation

Comment: if you need more help please either edit your question to include everything, or maybe even start a new question